# How to get the response from URL without cURL?

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I am working on twitter login integration with website. I don't have cURL installed in my server and I am not allowed to install that.

Twitter code is working fine for login. But while using `request_token` curl is used to send callback URL with that URL and getting the token response. In this same case I want to get the response from that URL without using `Curl` in PHP. Is it possible?

**Curl code now used:**

```
$response = curl_exec($ci);
```

The above response I need without using Curl.

Comment: For the REST API CURL is a way for the client to send the request and its more like HTTP request. CURL is often used since it is easy to send POST data, however if its just GET then you can built the query string and then use PHP function file_get_contents() as mentioned by @Hanky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How to get the response from url without Curl

You don't have to necessarily use cURL, there can be many ways. One of those is:

```
$response=file_get_contents($ci);
```

**Edit:**

You can also use `fsockopen`, here is an example from [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/function.fsockopen)

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: That Question is repeated in the answer for the trigger happy downvoters

Comment: I don't know who minus you, but I agree with this answer. Get my plus.

Comment: when i use file_get_contents then i am getting warning as  "Unable to find the wrapper &quot;https&quot; -"

Comment: You have to prepare your request url according to what the server expects you to send

Comment: minus not a pblm. i want answer what i am going to do with reputation? will stackoverflow pay me for that??

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky +1 yes file_get_contents() are very useful for REST API call.

Comment: allow_url_fopen is also not there.. without that how can i do? :( not able to set using ini_set()

Comment: Also ive a question for you, `Twitter code is working fine for login`: How does that work then?

Comment: (Unable to find the socket transport\